# Invalid syntax python else:

Tags: python

In my python script I'm getting `invalid syntax` in an else row, but I'm not understanding why. I post here my code:

```
if os.path.isfile('number.txt'):
            print('ESISTE')
            f = open('number.txt', 'r')
            data = f.read()
            f.close()
            listOfNumber = data[0:12]
            if jid[0:12] in listOfNumber:
                print("PRESENTE")
            else:
                print("DA INSERIRE")
                numberAndMessage = jid[0:12] + " " + messageContent
                listNumberAndMessage.append(data)
                listNumberAndMessage.append(numberAndMessage)

                f = open('number.txt', 'w')
                for item in listNumberAndMessage:
                    f.write("%s\n" % item)
                f.close()
        else: #line with error
            print('NON ESISTE')
```

Can you help me to understand why I'm getting this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Make sure your whitespace is aligned.

Comment: As @marshall.ward said, your first `if` and last `else` need to have the same indentation level.

Comment: Please can you us your traceback because your last 'else' is not indented well.

Comment: Specifically, `else:` must be directly aligned to the corresponding `if`. Leading whitespace in Python is like curly braces in C: you have to count and balance them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is all over the place - indentation should be in 4 white space blocks, and if and else statements should line up.
A guide to python styling - http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out

```
if os.path.isfile('number.txt'):
    print('ESISTE')
    f = open('number.txt', 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    listOfNumber = data[0:12]
    if jid[0:12] in listOfNumber:
        print("PRESENTE")
    else:
        print("DA INSERIRE")
        numberAndMessage = jid[0:12] + " " + messageContent
        listNumberAndMessage.append(data)
        listNumberAndMessage.append(numberAndMessage)

        f = open('number.txt', 'w')
        for item in listNumberAndMessage:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
        f.close()
else: #line with error
    print('NON ESISTE')
```